# one of services started with docker-compose up doesn't stop with docker-compose stop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the file `docker-compose.production.yml` that contains configurations of 5 services. I start them all with the command `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up --build` in the directory where the file is. When I want to stop all the services, I simply call `sudo docker-compose stop` in the directory where the file is. Strangely, 4 out of 5 services stop correctly, but 1 keeps running and if I want to stop it, I must use `sudo docker stop [CONTAINER]`. The service is not event being listed in the list of services that are being stopped after the `stop` command is run. It's like the service somehow "detaches" from the group. What could be causing this strange behaviour?

Here's an example of the `docker-compose.production.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  fe:
    build:
      context: ./fe
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    restart: always

  be:
    image: strapi/strapi:3.4.6-node12
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      DATABASE_CLIENT: mysql
      DATABASE_NAME: some_db
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      DATABASE_USERNAME: someuser
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD:?no database password specified}
      URL: https://some-url.com
    volumes:
      - ./be:/srv/app
      - ${SOME_DIRECTORY:?no directory specified}:/srv/something:ro
      - ./some-directory:/srv/something-else
    expose:
      - 1447
    ports:
      - 5001:1337
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: bash -c "yarn install && yarn build && yarn start"
    restart: always

  watcher:
    build:
      context: ./watcher
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      LICENSE_KEY: ${LICENSE_KEY:?no license key specified}
    volumes:
      - ./watcher:/usr/src/app
      - ${SOME_DIRECTORY:?no directory specified}:/usr/src/something:ro

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD:?no database password specified}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: some_db
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always

  db-backup:
    build:
      context: ./db-backup
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_DATABASE: some_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD:?no database password specified}
    volumes:
      - ./db-backup/backups:/backups
    restart: always
```

The service that doesn't stop together with others is the last one - `db-backup`. Here's an example of its `Dockerfile.production`:

```
FROM alpine:3.13.1

COPY ./scripts/startup.sh /usr/local/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/startup.sh

# NOTE used for testing when needs to run cron tasks more frequently
# RUN mkdir /etc/periodic/1min
COPY ./cron/daily/* /etc/periodic/daily
RUN chmod +x /etc/periodic/daily/*

RUN sh /usr/local/startup.sh

CMD [ "crond", "-f", "-l", "8"]
```

And here's an example of the `./scripts/startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running startup script"

echo "Checking if mysql-client is installed"

apk update

if ! apk info | grep -Fxq "mysql-client";
then
  echo "Installing MySQL client"

  apk add mysql-client

  echo "MySQL client installed"
fi

# NOTE this was used for testing. backups should run daily, thus script should
# normally be placed in /etc/periodic/daily/
# cron_task_line="*       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/1min"
# if ! crontab -l | grep -Fxq "$cron_task_line";
# then
#   echo "Enabling cron 1min periodic tasks"

#   echo -e "${cron_task_line}\n" >> /etc/crontabs/root
# fi

echo "Startup script finished"
```

All this happens on all the Ubuntu 18.04 machines that I've tried running this on. Didn't try it on anything else.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `./scripts/startup.sh` ?

Comment: @emi yes, I've added it to the question.

Comment: Can you post the processes running inside the problematic container after stopping all services with `docker-compose stop` ? (Tip: `ps x -H` from host may help)

Comment: @emi I'll post tomorrow, as it's late now, but the thing is, when I call `docker-compose stop`, I get a line in the shell for each service that says that the service is stopping, but there's no line printed for the problematic service, as it didn't even exist in the config. How about that?

Comment: _"as it didn't event exist in the config"_ What do you mean?

Comment: @emi as IF it didn't exist... The `stop` command behaves as if the service wasn't there at all.

Comment: Don't forget to post the process(es) running into the container after the stop command.